# CSS selector for hideous table-driven markup

Tags: css

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dc9wdwem/

I inherited a legacy application that some clients are still using and expecting upgrades for. One recent upgrade "broke" the existing CSS and the easiest way to resolve it is to "un-break" just one little table.

The markup is nested table upon nested table. But for the sake of stripping down to the bare essentials, here's the barest version of where to find my table.

```
<div id="someId">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table> <!-- not this table --> </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table> <!-- THIS ONE!! --> </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

There are other tables and rows and cells scattered throughout, but this structure gets you there.

Using the "direct descendant" symbol is tricky because the tables are descended within rows and cells as well as other tables. So `table>table>table` isn't going to do it. But then if you go with a general descendent selector, you end up selecting too many things `table table table` will get you a whole bunch of tables. Here's the closest I got so far:

```
#someId>table table td:nth-child(2) table {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I would normally be glad to add even more `>` selectors; however, I believe the browsers themselves are filling in `tbody` elements and so forth and I don't know that I can reasonably predict that the proper structure will always be intact. The above selector is selecting more tables than the one I'm trying to isolate.

None of the nested tables have IDs or classes, and nor do I have the opportunity to add them in. The upgrade process does not upgrade the customer's markup, which they may have themselves partially customized over time.

Anybody have any CSS selector magic that will work, assuming the above markup alongside browser-filled elements like `tbody`?

Comment: Are there any other attributes that you can target other than `class` and `id`?

Comment: `#someId table table table td:nth-of-type(2) table`? https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3wjy8k6b/

Comment: Thanks, j. I had provided incorrect markup by one extra table. Definitely removing the ">" is going to select even more tables than before. I only want to select the one.

Comment: Could you add the actual crazy markup to a fiddle? Would be useful to see.

Comment: Fiddle added: https://jsfiddle.net/dc9wdwem/

Comment: Is there a minimum browser version for this? There are some pretty amazing CSS selectors out there, but support in, say, IE8 is going to be dismal :).

Comment: Mike, I'll take what I can get. The rest of the company's products are IE9 and up only, so I believe that'll apply here. It's less about the legacy users (they're not old school or anything) and more about the legacy markup. Thanks for putting your eyes to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for the specific HTML in [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dc9wdwem/):

```css
#someId>table table:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(2) table {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Obviously, if the HTML changes in pretty much any way, this is probably not going to work.

Comment: @GregPettit - if you wanted multiple tables to be selected at some point, you could chain some not selectors together [like this example](https://jsfiddle.net/666wcwpq/). It would be appropriately messy CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a Table in your css.

try:

```
div#someId > table table table td:nth-child(2) > table
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ba52Lwkg/

```
#someId > table table:first-of-type td + td > table
```

this should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/dc9wdwem/

Comment: Ugh, sorry to have wasted your time thus far-- I had one too many tables in my sample markup, but the selector was "working". The problem wasn't that I could get the table at all, but that I was getting other unwanted tables in addition to the one I wanted. Thanks for your continued help and sorry again!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/LdkdujsL/ maybe this could help #someId > table table:first-of-type td + td > table {

Comment: Hultman, this worked, too!! I noticed Mike's response first. Dangit, SO needs a "multiple answers worked equally" function.